# Why smbclient -L returns info where OS=[Windows] if Samba server installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Samba server works on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64).
When I use smbclient for looking on available services on this server

```
smbclient -L server_name
```

I get this information:

> Domain=[WORKGROUP] **OS=[Windows 6.1]** Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

Could anybody explain what means "OS" and why there is written windows 6.1?

Comment: SMB is protocol created by Microsoft, so probably it doesn't allow to specify Operating Systems other than Windows, so that Samba chooses to report some arbitrary value.

Comment: @el.pescado it isn't true, this is an example: Domain=[VALE] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.22]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably late, but I was wondering myself and it can help someone else.

It's apparently [hardcoded](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/blob/52744d35a37680c382800539a4c88d553496dbec/source3/smbd/sesssetup.c#L50) to [fix](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/commit/666948c776948a8147501d2ba590bcd05e78458d) a [bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10168).

```
fstr_sprintf(native_os, "Windows %d.%d", SAMBA_MAJOR_NBT_ANNOUNCE_VERSION,
    SAMBA_MINOR_NBT_ANNOUNCE_VERSION);
```

> When the native os in sessionsetup is "Unix" then broken Konica
> Minolta printers refuse to talk to those CIFS servers. Other CIFS
> servers also announce themselves with native os Windows. Let's do the
> same to improve interoperability with broken devices like those
> printers from Konica Minolta. Thanks to Daniel Hoffmann for finding
> and reporting this Konika printer brokenness.
>
> https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10168

Answer (score -1):

`smblient -l` show you what services are available on the server (Ubuntu).

OS means Operating System of the client and Windows 6.1 is the version number of Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, for other system version number you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thank you for your answer! But I use smbclient on Ubuntu server to check the localhost and in this case I suppose the output should be OS=[UNIX] if it works as you said.